# Video streaming vs Video file transfer

Tags: video-streaming, ethernet

When transfetting video over usb from some local station to a remote station, it can be donw in several ways:

1. Tranfer the video as a file, with the same method available for transfering regular files.
2. Transfer the video stream using video streamer method such as MPEG-2 Transport stream.

I undestand that probably the 2nd option is better in terms of lateny issue, i.e. when the remote station will play the video at the same time.

But in there are many other cases that there is no such latency/real-time requirement, i.e. someone will watch the video later.

I would like to ask the 1st appraoch is better in such configuration, where there is no latency and real-time requirements.

Comment: You'll likely find more success with this question on Super User instead of Stack Overflow, since this site is for programming questions. I can probably advise you on Super User but please provide more details - what are you trying to accomplish, what constraints exist, what is the source of your video and so forth.

Comment: Thanks Sander, I'll do that.